# ClassCastException in NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType>

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-lambda, gson, aws-sdk

I am following the "best practices"(?) from the GitHub sample: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt

I am getting an error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.xxx.yyy.data.model.TestUser

I've tried using Gson to convert to JSON and back to the Generic RequestType, but that doesn't work either. The data is coming back just fine. If I cast the response in the `NetworkBoundResource`, then it works - but that kind of defeats the purpose of generics. I am also using the aws-android-sdk to invoke lambda, which makes things a HUGE pain, but that's AWS for ya

**TestUser**

```
public class TestUser {
    private String username;

    public TestUser() {

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**NetworkBoundResource**

```
abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType>
@MainThread constructor(private val appExecutors: AppExecutors) {

    private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>>()

    init {
        result.value = Resource.loading(null)

        val dbSource = loadFromDb()
        result.addSource(dbSource) { data ->
            result.removeSource(dbSource)
            if (shouldFetch(data)) {
                Log.e("NetworkBoundResource", "fetching from network")
                appExecutors.networkIO().execute {
                    fetchFromNetwork(dbSource)
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("NetworkBoundResource", "not fetching from network")
                result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                    setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    private fun setValue(newValue: Resource<ResultType>) {
        if (result.value != newValue) {
            result.value = newValue
        }
    }

    private fun fetchFromNetwork(dbSource: LiveData<ResultType>) {
        val apiResponse = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>>()

        // This is super dumb, but can't createCall() on the main thread 
        var lambdaResponse: LambdaResponse<RequestType>? = null
        var exception: Exception? = null

        try {
            lambdaResponse = createCall()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            exception = e
        }

        appExecutors.mainThread().execute {

            // Can't setValue on a background thread 
            if (exception != null) {
                apiResponse.value = ApiResponse.create(exception)
            } else if (lambdaResponse != null) {
                apiResponse.value = ApiResponse.create(lambdaResponse)
            }

            // we re-attach dbSource as a new source, it will dispatch its latest value quickly
            result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                setValue(Resource.loading(newData))
            }
            result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
                result.removeSource(apiResponse)
                result.removeSource(dbSource)
                when (response) {
                    is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                        appExecutors.diskIO().execute {
                            val x = processResponse(response)

                            // FAILING HERE
                            saveCallResult(x)
                            appExecutors.mainThread().execute {
                                // we specially request a new live data,
                                // otherwise we will get immediately last cached value,
                                // which may not be updated with latest results received from network.
                                result.addSource(loadFromDb()) { newData ->
                                    setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    is ApiEmptyResponse -> {
                        appExecutors.mainThread().execute {
                            // reload from disk whatever we had
                            result.addSource(loadFromDb()) { newData ->
                                setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                        onFetchFailed()
                        result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                            setValue(Resource.error(response.errorMessage, newData))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected open fun onFetchFailed() {
        Log.e("NetworkBoundResource", "onFetchFailed")
    }

    fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<Resource<ResultType>>

    @WorkerThread
    protected open fun processResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<RequestType>) = response.body

    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract fun saveCallResult(item: RequestType)

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun shouldFetch(data: ResultType?): Boolean

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<ResultType>

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun createCall(): LambdaResponse<RequestType>
}
```

**LoginDataSource**

```
fun auth(authRequest: AuthRequest): LiveData<Resource<User>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundResource<User, TestUser>(appExecutors) {
        override fun saveCallResult(item: TestUser) {
            Log.e("username", item.username)
            // Log.e("saveCallResult", "saving user to db: ${item.federatedIdentity}")
            // userDao.insertAll(item)
        }

        override fun shouldFetch(data: User?): Boolean {
            val fetch = data == null
            Log.e("shouldFetch", "$fetch")
            return true
        }

        override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<User> {
            Log.e("loadFromDb", "findById: ${authRequest.federatedIdentity}")
            return userDao.findById(authRequest.federatedIdentity)
        }

        override fun createCall(): LambdaResponse<TestUser> {
            Log.e("createCall", "authenticating user: ${authRequest.federatedIdentity}")
            return authApiService.auth(authRequest)
        }
    }.asLiveData()
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your API response along with `authApiService` interface code also ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the libraries you are using, but the issue might be that you are using a type variable (`RequestType`?) as type for Gson deserialization. Due to Java's type erasure, at runtime the type of the type variable is unknown so Gson deserializes it as Object (`com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` is Gson's internal representation for that). You would either somehow have to pass the expected type to Gson; or if the type is dynamic somehow encode it in the JSON data. But I am not sure how to do that with these libraries.